# How do I make this code block to finish executing before other codes after it?

Tags: javascript, async-await, map-function

I have been desperately trying to make a call to the "`Feature`" model before moving to `(if(serviceExists===undefined))` line as shown below but to no avail. I thought `async await` was the way to go but it doesn't help either.

I have tried putting the first if block in a Promise and resolving the `serviceExists` to a variable for Promise but that didn't work either. The code flow simply waits for the Feature.query to fetch the features and goes on to the 2nd if block i.e `(if(serviceExists === undefined))`.
And the execution of that block depends on the previous one. The flow never reaches the "base" check (i.e. 1st if block in the 1st outside if block). How do I make it such that it waits for the result from Feature model before further execution?

```
 let clientFeatures = await ClientFeature.query("clientId")
    .eq(clientMongoId)
    .exec();

  if (clientFeatures.length > 0) {
    var serviceExists;
    clientFeatures.map(async item => {
      let existingFeature = await Feature.queryOne("id")
        .eq(item.featureId)
        .exec();
      let existingFeatureType = existingFeature.type;
      if (
        existingFeatureType === "base" &&
        reSelectedFeatureType === "base"
      ) {
        existingBaseFeatureId = existingFeature.id;
        if (existingBaseFeatureId === reSelectedFeature[0].id) {
          serviceExists = true;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  if (serviceExists === undefined) {
    var clientFeatureGen = await ClientFeature.create({
      id: uuidv1(),
      clientId: clientMongoId,
      featureId: featureMongoId
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using asynchronous function in `map` you should "wait" for all promises that it creates using `Promise.all`

See this [post](https://medium.com/@ian.mundy/async-map-in-javascript-b19439f0099) for details and CodePen example.

Code taken from the CodePen:

```
const arr = [ { key: 1 }, { key: 2 }, { key: 3 } ]
const results = arr.map(async (obj) => { return obj.key; });
Promise.all(results).then((completed) => document.writeln( `\nResult: ${completed}`));
```

Comment: Could you  please show me a use case for my code? This doesn't seem to be easy to apply for my code.

Comment: `const features = clientFeatures.map(async item => { ... }); Promise.all(features).then(...)`